# Parallelization with the cooccur package function in r

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am computing cooccurrences of species in very huge datasets using the cooccur package.
This package is based on a probabilistic model which is very demanding in term of calculations.

Thus, I was wondering how could I parallelize the calculation to have faster results.
I have seen that packages like `doParallel` or `snowfall` could do the job but I tried to use them and did not really succeed since they need a loop structure.

```
install.packages("cooccur")
library(cooccur)
data(finches)
system.time(
  co <- cooccur(finches, thresh = FALSE, spp_names = TRUE)
)
```

With this example, the computation is fast but it's very slow with bigger datasets.

Note that on Ubuntu the coocur package relies on `gmp` which needs `sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you wanted to parallelize this function you'd have to jump into the function itself and see which (if any) of the nested loops can be pulled apart.  There there are /tons/ of loops.

Which nested loops cause you the most problems (and should be parallelized) may depend on your particular problem and particular dataset.  To help diagnose the issue, consider using hadley's profiling function (below) to help identify places you might rewrite the function.  Keep in mind you may want to run your profiling tests (and speed tests) with a relatively large amount of data so you can find the right places to trim.  At which point, you should also consider whether it is [worth the time](https://xkcd.com/1205/).

```
library(cooccur)
library(devtools)
library(lineprof)
data(finches)
devtools::install_github("hadley/lineprof")
l <- lineprof(co <- cooccur(finches, thresh = FALSE, spp_names = TRUE))
shine(l)
```

To start off, you might want to look at the big 1:nrow(obs_coocur) loop.  In tests with the finch dataset I wasn't able to eek out a speed up and the results seemed somewhat degenerate (lots of NA rows needed to be cleaned out and even then the results weren't identical).

Abandoned draft function below:

```
mcsapply <- function (X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
{
  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  answer <- mclapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
  if (USE.NAMES && is.character(X) && is.null(names(answer))) 
    names(answer) <- X
  if (!identical(simplify, FALSE) && length(answer)) 
    simplify2array(answer, higher = (simplify == "array"))
  else answer
}

cooccurLocal <- function (mat, type = "spp_site", thresh = TRUE, spp_names = FALSE, 
    true_rand_classifier = 0.1, prob = "hyper", only_effects = FALSE, 
    eff_standard = TRUE, eff_matrix = FALSE) 
{
    if (type == "spp_site") {
        spp_site_mat <- mat
    }
    if (type == "site_spp") {
        spp_site_mat <- t(mat)
    }
    if (spp_names == TRUE) {
        spp_key <- data.frame(num = 1:nrow(spp_site_mat), spp = row.names(spp_site_mat))
    }
    spp_site_mat[spp_site_mat > 0] <- 1
    nsite <- ncol(spp_site_mat)
    nspp <- nrow(spp_site_mat)
    spp_pairs <- choose(nspp, 2)
    incidence <- prob_occur <- matrix(nrow = nspp, ncol = 2)
    obs_cooccur <- prob_cooccur <- exp_cooccur <- matrix(nrow = spp_pairs, 
        ncol = 3)
    prob_share_site <- c(0:(nsite + 1))
    incidence <- cbind(c(1:nrow(spp_site_mat)), rowSums(spp_site_mat, 
        na.rm = T))
    prob_occur <- cbind(c(1:nrow(spp_site_mat)), rowSums(spp_site_mat, 
        na.rm = T)/nsite)
    pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = (nspp + nrow(obs_cooccur)), 
        style = 3)
    row <- 0
    for (spp in 1:nspp) {
        if (spp < nspp) {
            for (spp_next in (spp + 1):nspp) {
                row <- row + 1
                pairs <- 0
                for (site in 1:nsite) {
                  if (spp_site_mat[spp, site] > 0 & spp_site_mat[spp_next, 
                    site] > 0) {
                    pairs <- pairs + 1
                  }
                }
                obs_cooccur[row, 1] <- spp
                obs_cooccur[row, 2] <- spp_next
                obs_cooccur[row, 3] <- pairs
                prob_cooccur[row, 1] <- spp
                prob_cooccur[row, 2] <- spp_next
                prob_cooccur[row, 3] <- prob_occur[spp, 2] * 
                  prob_occur[spp_next, 2]
                exp_cooccur[row, 1] <- spp
                exp_cooccur[row, 2] <- spp_next
                exp_cooccur[row, 3] <- prob_cooccur[row, 3] * 
                  nsite
            }
        }
        setTxtProgressBar(pb, spp)
    }
    if (thresh == TRUE) {
        n_pairs <- nrow(prob_cooccur)
        prob_cooccur <- prob_cooccur[exp_cooccur[, 3] >= 1, ]
        obs_cooccur <- obs_cooccur[exp_cooccur[, 3] >= 1, ]
        exp_cooccur <- exp_cooccur[exp_cooccur[, 3] >= 1, ]
        n_omitted <- n_pairs - nrow(prob_cooccur)
        pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = (nspp + nrow(obs_cooccur)), 
            style = 3)
    }
    output <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 9))
    colnames(output) <- c("sp1", "sp2", "sp1_inc", "sp2_inc", 
        "obs_cooccur", "prob_cooccur", "exp_cooccur", "p_lt", 
        "p_gt")
    output <- mcsapply(1:nrow(obs_cooccur), function(row) {
        sp1 <- obs_cooccur[row, 1]
        sp2 <- obs_cooccur[row, 2]
        sp1_inc <- incidence[incidence[, 1] == sp1, 2]
        sp2_inc <- incidence[incidence[, 1] == sp2, 2]
        max_inc <- max(sp1_inc, sp2_inc)
        min_inc <- min(sp1_inc, sp2_inc)
        prob_share_site <- rep(0, (nsite + 1))
        if (prob == "hyper") {
            if (only_effects == FALSE) {
                all.probs <- phyper(0:min_inc, min_inc, nsite - 
                  min_inc, max_inc)
                prob_share_site[1] <- all.probs[1]
                for (j in 2:length(all.probs)) {
                  prob_share_site[j] <- all.probs[j] - all.probs[j - 
                    1]
                }
            }
            else {
                for (j in 0:nsite) {
                  if ((sp1_inc + sp2_inc) <= (nsite + j)) {
                    if (j <= min_inc) {
                      prob_share_site[(j + 1)] <- 1
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
        if (prob == "comb") {
            if (only_effects == FALSE) {
                for (j in 0:nsite) {
                  if ((sp1_inc + sp2_inc) <= (nsite + j)) {
                    if (j <= min_inc) {
                      prob_share_site[(j + 1)] <- coprob(max_inc = max_inc, 
                        j = j, min_inc = min_inc, nsite = nsite)
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
            else {
                for (j in 0:nsite) {
                  if ((sp1_inc + sp2_inc) <= (nsite + j)) {
                    if (j <= min_inc) {
                      prob_share_site[(j + 1)] <- 1
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
        p_lt <- 0
        p_gt <- 0
        for (j in 0:nsite) {
            if (j <= obs_cooccur[row, 3]) {
                p_lt <- prob_share_site[(j + 1)] + p_lt
            }
            if (j >= obs_cooccur[row, 3]) {
                p_gt <- prob_share_site[(j + 1)] + p_gt
            }
            if (j == obs_cooccur[row, 3]) {
                p_exactly_obs <- prob_share_site[(j + 1)]
            }
        }
        p_lt <- round(p_lt, 5)
        p_gt <- round(p_gt, 5)
        p_exactly_obs <- round(p_exactly_obs, 5)
        prob_cooccur[row, 3] <- round(prob_cooccur[row, 3], 3)
        exp_cooccur[row, 3] <- round(exp_cooccur[row, 3], 1)
        output[row, ] <- c(sp1, sp2, sp1_inc, sp2_inc, obs_cooccur[row, 
            3], prob_cooccur[row, 3], exp_cooccur[row, 3], p_lt, 
            p_gt)
        return(output)
    }, simplify=FALSE)
    output <- do.call("rbind", output)
    output <- output[!is.na(output$sp1),]
    close(pb)
    if (spp_names == TRUE) {
        sp1_name <- merge(x = data.frame(order = 1:length(output$sp1), 
            sp1 = output$sp1), y = spp_key, by.x = "sp1", by.y = "num", 
            all.x = T, sort = FALSE)
        sp2_name <- merge(x = data.frame(order = 1:length(output$sp2), 
            sp2 = output$sp2), y = spp_key, by.x = "sp2", by.y = "num", 
            all.x = T, sort = FALSE)
        output$sp1_name <- sp1_name[with(sp1_name, order(order)), 
            "spp"]
        output$sp2_name <- sp2_name[with(sp2_name, order(order)), 
            "spp"]
    }
    true_rand <- (nrow(output[(output$p_gt >= 0.05 & output$p_lt >= 
        0.05) & (abs(output$obs_cooccur - output$exp_cooccur) <= 
        (nsite * true_rand_classifier)), ]))
    output_list <- list(call = match.call(), results = output, 
        positive = nrow(output[output$p_gt < 0.05, ]), negative = nrow(output[output$p_lt < 
            0.05, ]), co_occurrences = (nrow(output[output$p_gt < 
            0.05 | output$p_lt < 0.05, ])), pairs = nrow(output), 
        random = true_rand, unclassifiable = nrow(output) - (true_rand + 
            nrow(output[output$p_gt < 0.05, ]) + nrow(output[output$p_lt < 
            0.05, ])), sites = nsite, species = nspp, percent_sig = (((nrow(output[output$p_gt < 
            0.05 | output$p_lt < 0.05, ])))/(nrow(output))) * 
            100, true_rand_classifier = true_rand_classifier)
    if (spp_names == TRUE) {
        output_list$spp_key <- spp_key
        output_list$spp.names = row.names(spp_site_mat)
    }
    else {
        output_list$spp.names = c(1:nrow(spp_site_mat))
    }
    if (thresh == TRUE) {
        output_list$omitted <- n_omitted
        output_list$pot_pairs <- n_pairs
    }
    class(output_list) <- "cooccur"
    if (only_effects == F) {
        output_list
    }
    else {
        effect.sizes(mod = output_list, standardized = eff_standard, 
            matrix = eff_matrix)
    }
}
```